# Current distribution in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current, density-operator, hydrogen

In the Bohr model of hydrogen, the electron orbits the proton at selected radii such that the angular momentum is quantized in integer multiples of $\hbar$. We can then associate a current with such a moving charge. But in standard QM, we describe the hydrogen atom in terms of stationary states and electron wave functions. Is it still possible to describe the current density in this case?

In particular, I am interested in the hydrogen atom in thermal state $\rho = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta H}$. I want to calculate the current density $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x})$. I am thinking of using the probability current multiplied by the electron charge
$$
\hat{\mathbf{J}} = \frac{(-e)}{2m}(\Psi^* \hat{\mathbf{p}} \Psi - \Psi \hat{\mathbf{p}} \Psi^* - 2 (-e) \mathbf{A} |\Psi|^2)
$$

and to calculate the expectation value I use
$$
\langle \hat{J_i} \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho \hat{J_i})
$$

Is this the correct way to do it? By symmetry, I expect the result to be zero. But there might be a persistent current when there is an external magnetic field? In classical electrodynamics, a moving charged particle in a uniform magnetic field will trace out a helix. With a fixed B field, the orientation/direction of the helix (how the charge orbits when view from "above") is determined by the sign of the charge and does not depend on the initial velocity. This then gives us either clockwise or counterclockwise current?